# Wordpress: Using PHP or .htaccess to change name

Tags: php, .htaccess, wordpress

I am aiming for clean URL's in my WP site, currently I have the following example:

**Example:**

PluginName: = gft_galleries

pageTitle: = gallery-one

`http://domain.co.nz/pluginName/pageTitle/`

Is there away within Wordpress or .htaccess to create the following but keep the correct structure underneath?

**Example:**

`http://domain.co.nz/galleries/pageTitle`

**.htAccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%2/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^gft_gallery/(.*)$ /gallery/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is this.

Add it to your .htaccess, if its wordpress though, your
rewrite engine will probably already be on, so omit that
line

```
#modified ;)
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^gft_gallery/(.*)$ /gallery/$1 [L]
```

I guess another simple way to do this is with symlinks, by typing

```
$ ln -s gft_gallery/ gallery
```

into your terminal, or via a script

```
<?php symlink('gft_gallery','gallery'); ?>
```

remember if you use the PHP method above to add `Options FollowSymLinks` in 
either your apache.conf or htacces

Comment: Thanks,  I have placed my .htaccess into the question and it has not worked Have I got it in the correct location?

Comment: try putting it as the last line, you might need a condition for it too

Comment: What do you mean by condition?

Comment: here try this instead `RewriteRule ^gallery/(.*)$ /gft_gallery/$1 [L]`

Comment: Ok I can now access via /gallery/ but how would I change the uri as this does not seem to be happening would the symlink do this?

Comment: This should do the trick: http://blinktag.com/how-to-find-replace-in-mysql-for-wordpress-permalinks-that-have-changed/ make sure to back up your database before you try this though.